# Updating ManyToOne Object With Full Reference

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have 2 Entities:

```
public class Brand {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonView(Views.Detailed.class)
  @JsonManagedReference("brand-departments")
  private List<Department> departments;

}

public class Department {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference("brand-departments")
  private Brand brand;
}
```

When updating a `Department`, I'm doing the following in my controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> update(@PathVariable Long brandId,
                       @Valid @RequestBody Department department, BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException("Invalid Department", bindingResult);
    }

    Department existingDepartment = departmentService.findById(department.getId());
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(department, existingDepartment, "brand");
    this.departmentService.update(existingDepartment);
    MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = jsonView(JSON_VIEWS.SUMMARY.value, department);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(mappingJacksonValue, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The reason I ignore `brand` when copying the properties is because the brand comes in NULL for the `@RequestBody Department department`. When I look up the `existingDepartment` it has the right Brand. However, when I update the department, it fails because it says `BRAND_ID` is NULL. But I've verified that it isn't NULL.

If I do the following:

```
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> update(@PathVariable Long brandId,
               @Valid @RequestBody Department department, BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException("Invalid Department", bindingResult);
    }

    Department existingDepartment = departmentService.findById(department.getId());
    existingBrand.setBrand(new Brand(brandId));
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(department, existingDepartment);
    this.departmentService.update(existingDepartment);
    MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = jsonView(JSON_VIEWS.SUMMARY.value, department);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(mappingJacksonValue, HttpStatus.OK);
```

}

(setting the `brand` on `existingDepartment` to just be a non-session-connected object with just an ID) the update works correctly. So there's something about the fact that `existingDepartment` has a reference to a full blown database fetched version of `brand` that is causing the update to fail, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Apart from the brand problem, there's something I don't understand in your code. You copy all the property values from your existing department to the one coming as a parameter. That way, aren't you always overwriting the values coming in the request with the ones already persisted?

Comment: Yes, which is what I want. If they're the same, no real change. If they are different, that's what actually needs updated.

Comment: Ah Ok, I understand, you are using the Spring's BeanUtils. I thought you were using the one from Apache Commons, which has the parameters reversed. But, in that case, you should call your _departmentService.update_ method using the _existingDepartment_ instance instead of the _department_ one. I don't know why it works in your second example, unless that _existingBrand_ variable which seems to be wrong is actually _department_.

Comment: Yep, that was a typo on my part. I'll fix the question. The issue still exists, as my actual code is correct that I'm testing.